# How can I play a sound when clicking on a image, that goes to a link when the sound is done?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to add an image to my html that, when clicked, will call a function that would play a sound, then when the sound is done playing take you to another website/link. I'm not sure of a way of doing this and have looked at various websites and articles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First you need to add a [click event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to an `<img>` tag.
2. You need an [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag in order to play sound.
3. You can trigger [play()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play_event) using the event registered on step 1
4. Add an [ended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event to the audio tag to know when the audio ended
5. Use [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to navigate to another URL

You can hide the audio player if you want using styles.

```js
const audio = document.querySelector('#audio');
audio.load(); //call this to preload the audio without playing

const picture = document.querySelector('#picture');

//add onclick event to image
picture.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  //call this to play the audio right away
  audio.play();
});

// register an event to know when the audio ended
audio.addEventListener('ended', (e) => {

  // go to another url
  location.href = 'https://w3.org';

});
```

```css
audio {
  /* uncomment to hide the player */
  /* display: none; */
}
```

```html
<p>Click the image to play sound</p>
<img id="picture" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/poster.png" width="200">

<br>

<audio id="audio" controls="controls">
  <source id="audioSource" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sound/sound_5.mp3"></source>
  Your browser does not support the audio format.
</audio>
```